# Why how and why this implicit conversion works

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I don't understand why c1 = {1, 2, 3, 4} and c2 = {5, 6, 7, 8} works fine, there are no declared constructors, and compiler-generated compilers doesn't fit.

I tried to understand by making conversion explicit: (C&) { 1, 2, 3, 4} and (const C&) { 1, 2, 3, 4}, but it doesn't work. If compiler provides default constructor with initializer list, or I'm taking the problem from the wrong side?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace A001 {
class A { public: int a; double b; };
class B { public: int a; double b; };
class C { public: A a; B b; };
void test() {
    C c1 = { 1,2,3,4 }, c2 = { 5,6,7,8 };
        cout << c1.b.a + c2.a.b;
   }
}
```

Comment: Read up on [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: Note that it's not, as written in the first paragraph of the question, `c1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}` and `c2 = {5, 6, 7, 8}`. It's `C c1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}` and (implicitly) `C c2 = {5, 6, 7, 8}`.

Comment: "compiler-generated compilers" you mean... constructors? Although there's something about compilers generated compilers that makes me think we've reached the end of history.

Comment: Yeah, I meant constructors, just was distracted a little bit. I'm acquainted with struct brace-initialization but met such a code with classes, so was a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an implicit conversion, it's [*aggregate initialization* + *brace elision*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). E.g.

```
C c1 = { 1,2,3,4 }
```

is equivalent to

```
C c1{ {1,2}, {3,4} }
```